# Remove temporary files after doing tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, temporary-files

During doing unit tests in Rails a few temp files are created (associated with model). When test is done I want to remove these files, so I have to find a way to do this no matter the test passes or not.
So, what are you suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not put the file creation in a setup and the destruction in a teardown function? Then the creation will run beforehand - no matter what - and the destruction will run afterwards - again, no matter what. If you want setup and teardown of these files only for certain conditions, there's a nice writeup on it here: http://technicalpickles.com/posts/rails-special-sauce-test-unit-setup-and-teardown/

Answer (score 1):

In a meanwhile I've tested something like this:

```
begin
  ...
  asserts
  ...
ensure
  delete_temporary_files
end
```

and it also works fine.